# Is it possible to use class library written in CORE 6 in another core 6 and/or NET 4.8 framework project

Tags: c#, .net, .net-6.0, visual-studio-2022, .net-4.8

I have a class library using core 6.0

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net6.0</TargetFramework>
    <ImplicitUsings>enable</ImplicitUsings>
    <Nullable>enable</Nullable>
  </PropertyGroup>

</Project>
```

[image]

I would like to use this library either in a core 6.0 framework project or in a WPF NET 4.8 framework. so actually, I cant reference the library core 6 in a project written in Net 4.8

I would like to use the same library (same source code) for both environments, how I could resolve my problem, is it possible to use a different configuration Framework for the same source code?

Comment: Short answer - you can't. The library would need to be .NET Standard 2.0 for it to be compatible with .NET Framework 4.8 and .NET 6

Comment: @Matt thanks for your respons,   so i have to have 2 projects differents in each framework 6.0 and 4.8?

Comment: It is not possible As far as I know.

Comment: @Frenchy, a single .NET Standard 2.0 library can be referenced by both .NET 6 and .NET Framework 4.8. If you need .NET 6 specific functionality that isn't in .NET Standard 2.0 then you'll have to create 2 libraries, that can't share code (could go 3 libraries, share what you can then add specifics into the specific libraries).

Comment: Try replacing `<TargetFramework>net6.0</TargetFramework>` with `<TargetFrameworks>net48;net6.0</TargetFrameworks>` and it should work.  (You'll have to remove the implicit usings and nullable stuff and constrain your class library to only use net48 level of C# support, but it'll allow your class library to be targeted by either framework type)

Answer (score -2):

Yes it is possible.
First you should use multiple frameworks and then you need to make nuget package of class library
here is the exampl
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qc2WFaMfdp8

Comment: No it's not, videos aren't references or answers, and multitargeting means actually providing a .NET Core/.NET Standard target. You're using a .NET Core library, not a .NET Framework library. The last question comment mentioned multitargeting already and showed how to do this with `<TargetFrameworks>net48;net6.0</TargetFrameworks>`

Comment: Link-only answers are not acceptable. Include the pertinent parts of the linked solution in your answer.